# how to choose the suitable parametric form given a boundary?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, parametric

Find the absolute minimum and maximum values of $g(x, y) = (x^2 + y^2)e^{(−x^2−4y^2)}$ on the set $A = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 + 4y^ 2 ≤ 4\}$.

here is the solution //see image 
[image]

so my question is when you use parametric form how do you know what value to set for $x$ and $y$ given the boundary and why exactly did he choose $x=2\cos\phi$ and $y=\sin\phi$ instead of $x=\cos\phi$ and $y=\sin\phi$ any links to videos will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the boundary is given by the form $x^2+4y^2≤4$ which can be written as $x^2+4y^2=4$ 
to parametrise an ellipse the following should be applied 
given the function for an ellipse $ (x-p)^2/(a)^2 + (y-q)^2/(b)^2 =1$
the parametrisation of the ellipse is as follows:
$ a * cos(t)-p$
$ b * sin(t)-q$

so in this case since $x^2+4y^2=4$ since the right hand side isn't $=1$ we need to divide by whatever its value is to get it to equal 1 hence
$ (x^2)/4+y^2=1$ this is in the form of an ellipse now and can be rewritten as $$(x-0)^2/(2)^2 +(y-0)^2/(1)^2 =1$$ which is equivalent to $$x^2/2^2 +y^2=1$$ and now applying the rule above we get the following $$x=2cos(t)$$ $$y=sin(t)$$
for more information regarding this topic please visit  [THIS YOUTUBE LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bukIJo6xydE)

Answer (score 1):

$A$ = {$x,y: x^2 + 4 y^2\leq4$}

So the boundary of A is
$x^2+4y^2 = 4$ or

$(x/2)^2 + y^2 = 1$

$x/2 = \cos \theta;y = \sin \theta $

Comment: i thought about it in this way:
$ x^2+4y^2=4$
so $1/4 x^2+y^2=1$
and if we set $x=2cosθ$
then we get $1/4*4cos^2 θ=cos^2 θ$
which means we get to the point were we started, i mean we know that pythagorean identity $x^2+y^2=1$ however this doesnt solve the problem it just puts an end to it.

Comment: I don't understand where the problem lies.  This is a standard parametric for an ellipse.